# Multiprofile with abstract model

Tags: python, django, abstract-class, user-profile

I need two type of profile:

1) the first linked to Users by onetoone relationship to expand it with some new fields.

2) the seconds indipendent from Users (and accessible only to superuser/admin): they are just objects.

The problem is that I want a easy way to change a profile from 1°type to second type and viceversa.

In "Django Designer Patterns " I find an example like this:

```
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    User_Types = (
        (0, 'active'),
        (1, 'inactive'),
    )
    user_type = models.IntegerField(null=True, choices=User_Types, default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    #many other common field

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile_Active(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='profile_active', primary_key=True) #this was in BaseProfile
    #some more field reserved for this type of profile

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Profile_Inactive(models.Model):
    #some field reserved for this type of profile

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Profile(Profile_Inactive, Profile_Active, BaseProfile):
    pass
```

but I don't understand how I should combine the abstract models in `Profile` (what I should write instead of "pass"?) and what I should achieve? `Profile`
will have all the fields of the three models? Which the gain respect to use a single model?

Maybe I can forget `Profile` and use `Profile_Inactive(BaseProfile)` and `Profile_Active(BaseProfile)`? but then how to change from one to the other?

I'm confused, help please